# Understanding TraversableOnce and Subtyping

Tags: scala

I am trying to implement a distinctBy method, I can do it easily enough for Seq, but being an adventurous fellow, I wanted to try doing something a little more generic.

```
def distinctBy[A, B, M[_] <: TraversableOnce[_]](xs: M[A])(f: A => B)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[A], A, M[A]]): M[A] = {

  val seen = mutable.Set.empty[B]
  val builder = cbf(xs)

  for (x <- xs) {
      val k = f(x)
      if (!seen.contains(k)) {
          seen += k
          builder += x
      }
  }

  builder.result()
}
```

The basic intuition here is that I map to a type and keep track of a set of those, rather than the equality defined on the elements of the original collection. So i could take the distinct set of tuples comparing just the left element, or the right.

I cannot get this to compile, even if I switch to using just forall, because it doesn't seem to think that xs has any of the methods defined on TraversableOnce, even though there is a subtyping relation. I am obviously missing something quite elementary here, and would be grateful for any help rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the constraint to be `M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]`. `_` is special, and with your current signature you will only know that `M[A] <: TraversableOnce[_]`, whereas you want `M[A] <: TraversableOnce[A]`.

You're missing a closing brace, which might be important.

What's the exact compilation error you're getting?

Comment: This was entirely the problem. I had copied the `M[_]` malarky from the implementation of `Future.traverse`. It seemed logical. I want a type of kind `* -> *` then in the signature I specify that xs is of type `M[A]` explicitly. The exact error was:

Comment: [error] /src/main/scala/com/sphonic/spark/common/RequiredFacts.scala:185: missing parameter type
    [error]       for (x <- xs) {
    [error]